# MVC Create Scaffold from Selected Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model:

```
[Key]
public int AssetID { get; set; }

[Required]
public string AssetNumber { get; set; }
public string AssetDescription { get; set; }
public int? ParentAssetID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ParentAssetID")]
public virtual AssetRegister Parent { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AssetRegister> Childs { get; set; }
```

Then I have the following Controller:

```
public ActionResult AssetRegisterCreate(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    AssetRegister assetRegister = db.AssetRegisters.Find(id);
    if (assetRegister == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(assetRegister);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AssetRegisterCreate([Bind(Include = "AssetNumber,AssetDescription,ParentAssetID")] AssetRegister assetRegister)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(assetRegister).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("TreeView");
     }
     return View(assetRegister);
 }
```

On the `TreeView` View, I have the following command:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AssetRegisterCreate", "AssetRegister", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="text" id="AssetID" name="id" />
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
}
```

After I click `Create` button, It will redirect me to `AssetRegister/AssetRegisterCreate?id=8` 
`id = 8` is the `AssetID`.

I create a Scaffold View on the `AssetRegisterCreate`:

My question is The AssetID should be a value for ParentID. How can I do that? Since the `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssetNumber)` is used by the selected AssetID? Do I need to create a new `@Html.EditorFor` ? But on which field?

Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Your `<input type="text" id="AssetID" name="id" />` does not have a value, so that is not posting anything (it does not generate `?id=8` unless you have set it somewhere)

Comment: And since you not editing it, you do not need a hidden input. You can just use `using (Html.BeginForm("AssetRegisterCreate", "AssetRegister", new { id = Model.ParentAssetID }, FormMethod.Get))` (and I suggest you follow convention, and rename the method to just `Create`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes, the value is coming from somewhere else. Too long if I include it on the question. But, the "AssetID" on the input will always change depend on the action on my View.

Comment: We cant help unless you show the relevant code :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, new { id = Model.ParentAssetID } .. The ID should be AssetID, because its to save as a ParentID.

Comment: But in your question you stated _The AssetID should be a value for ParentID_ - now its even more unclear and confusing

Comment: Your `Create` method is not making sense. The code in it is getting an existing `AssetRegister`, not creating one. Best guess is that you want t pass the `ParentID` and in the method initialize a new `AssetRegister` and set its `ParentAssetID` to the value you passed in